# Django Static wont Load

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I am learning how to use django but having difficulties using static files.

Files (`BASE_DIR` is `website`, App is `player`):

```
 Website
 └─── player
      └─── static
           └─── style.css
           └─── admin
```

In Settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'player/static')
```

In `index.html`:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{ static 'style.css' %}" >
```

In `style.css`:

```
body {
    background-color: blue
}
```

I have ran `collectstatic`.

When loaded, the HTML appears without the css.

The console reads:

```
[23/Nov/2016 23:33:13] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 278
Not Found: /{ static 'style.css' %}
[23/Nov/2016 23:33:13] "GET /%7B%20static%20'style.css'%20%%7D HTTP/1.1" 404      2172
```

Comment: Did you try making the settings: 1) `STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)`

2) `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles/')`
3) `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

Comment: @Hybrid Yes, even with those settings it still can't find the file.

Comment: Check your spelling in template directives for basic errors

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the ***python manage.py collectstatic***?

Comment: Yes, it added the files to static directory

Comment: do you have static route in your `urls.py`, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Answer (score 0):

Wrong directive in template:

```
{% load static %}
```

should be

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

**Update**

also not:

```
{ static 'style.css' %}
```

but

```
{% static 'style.css' %}
```

Basic spelling errors

Comment: I made these changes but it still responds with: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)